# SetValue in reflection in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider this code:

```
var future = new Future();
future.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).SetValue(future, converted);
```

In the code above we should pass two arguments  for `SetValue`. First,The object that we want to set its property. Second,the new value. But we select the specific property.

Why we should pass the first parameter to set the value as we have set the future object before!?

Comment: Reflection would be (more) hideously complex if every object had to remember *how* it was obtained, just so that it could use that retained information later rather than asking for it again via a parameter. I.e. there are many ways to obtain a `Type`, not all of which require an instance of that type first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the *future* object is an instance. The *PropertyInfo* is retrieved from the type (`Type type = future.GetType();`) and isn't bound to any instance. That's why you have to pass the instance in the *SetValue()*.

So:

```
var future = new Future();

var propertyName = "...";
Type type = future.GetType();
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

propertyInfo.SetValue(future, value);
```

You can reuse the *propertyInfo* to set properties of other instances.

Answer (score 4):

Here

```
future.GetType()
```

`future` was used only to obtain its type. Effectively it is the same as

```
Type t = future.GetType();
t.GetProperty(info.Name).SetValue(future, converted);
```

On the second line of the code above all the knowledge about what object was used to get the type is lost, and we are dealing with the type itself. Later, when we have information about the property of the type, we need to know what object it should be used with, so we are providing `future` yet again.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't set the future object before - you've simply extracted its type, and then operated on that. What you end up with is a `PropertyInfo` object that refers to that property on any instance of type `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do following:

```
typeof(Future).GetProperty(info.Name).SetValue(future, converted);
```

How could the instance be taken without `future` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Consider these 2 classes:

```
class Future
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
class FarFuture : Future { }
```

Take a look at this code:

```
var future = new Future();
var farFuture = new FarFuture();
future.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).SetValue(farFuture, converted);
```

The `PropertyInfo` is not bound to an instance, but to a type.