# Reflection PropertyInfo SetValue C#

Tags: c#, reflection, setvalue, propertyinfo

Im using reflection to get a property. I then want to change the value of this property.

For this example I want to get the property of type `Task` and overwrite that property value with a different `Task` object. This is my code so far. It's currently getting the `Task PropertyInfo` but I don't know what to put in the 1st parameter of the `SetValue` call.

```
var viewBindingProperty = viewBinding.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(Task).Name);

viewBindingProperty.SetValue(??, pageBinding.Task);
```

I need to overwrite the value of the Task Property value in the `viewBindingProperty` with `pageBinding.Task`

Comment: It's the object that you want the value to be set on. So in your case, most likely it is `viewBinding`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Instance (`viewBinding`) or `null` if the property is *static* one

Comment: Yup that was it, does anyone want to put it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I might sounds grumpy, but if you would try to search for **any** example of how to set value of `PropertyInfo`, then you would instantly see what is `??` there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SetValue in reflection in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181989/setvalue-in-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I actually did search and couldnt figure it so so I posted it here. I didnt automatically post this question. It was my last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that viewBinding is the object you want to change the value of

```
viewBindingProperty.SetValue(viewBinding, pageBinding.Task);
```

The first parameter takes the object that you want to assign the new value to.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BadDub No problem, just mark it as correct so that others can find it too!